# Vim default mapleader binds

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there are any keys bound to the mapleader key in Vim. Or put in other words: Does the mapleader key provide me with a full blank set of user defined keybinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are no default mapleader mappings. A lot of plugins use them though, so check if they already exist either via `:verbose map <binding>` or `:help hasmapto()`.

Oh, by the way, also check `:help maplocalleader`.